# Vite serving shader file with wrong (none) MIME type

Tags: mime-types, vite, content-type, babylonjs

I'm developing a BabylonJS application.  BabylonJS PostProcess class appends `.fragment.fx` to a given file name and requests that from the server.  When my local Vite (version 4.0.4) dev server serves this file the `content-type` header is empty.  This causes Firefox to intepret it as type `xml` and fail.  Chrome fails through a different, but I think related, mechanism.

[image: Error from .fragment.fx file interpretted as MIME type XML]

How do you configure Vite to serve the `*.fragment.fx` static files as `text/plain`?  I assume I need to disable the default middleware and write some custom code instead, like this: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-middlewaremode but I wanted to first check there wasn't something else going on / a simpler way to configure / fix this.

The vite dev server is started using `vite --host --port 3000 --force` and the config in `vite.config.js` is:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
    // if (command === 'serve') {
    //     return {
    //       // dev specific config
    //     }
    // } else {
    //     // command === 'build'
    //     return {
    //         // build specific config
    //     }
    // }


    return {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "babylonjs": mode === "development" ? "babylonjs/babylon.max" : "babylonjs",
            }
        },
        base: "",
        // assetsInclude: ['**/*.fx'],
    };
});
```

* edit 1 *

I have seen there's a [parameter `?raw`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string) that can be added to the URL however I don't control how BabylonJS forms the URL so I can't see how to make this work in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [these instructions](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html#setting-up-the-dev-server) and set up a dev server using express.  I added this block of code above the call to `app.use(vite.middlewares)`:

```js
  app.use("**/*.*.fx", async (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl

    const file_path = path.resolve(__dirname, "." + url)

    const file = fs.readFileSync(file_path, "utf-8")

    res.status(200).set({ "Content-Type": "text/plain" }).end(file)
  })
```

I now start the dev server using the following script line in the package.json of `"dev": "node server",`

I could not find a way to solve this by configuring the default vite dev server.